# How to use a c program to determine if the user entered a command that exists in linux

Tags: c, linux, shell, command-line, command

I'm doing this program that lets the user enter c string and then i want to make a function that checks if the string entered by the user is a linux command.
ex.
user: cat
output: cat is a command

user: hello
output: hello is not a command

etc...

I was told i could use execvp but i dont want to execute the command just to figure out it exists, i just want to determine if it exists.

I thought one could some how utilize the whereis command that linux has that outputs the location of a particular command, however i dont know how to implement this in c.

I was also told stat() could work but i'm not sure how since its marcos only change for directories and files. So are commands like cat files? If so when i do run stat like:

stat( cmd, &buff );

wouldn't i need the cmd's path?

Overall how can i determine if a user entered a valid command in linux using c and let the solution be relatively protable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a combination of the Linux `which` command and the C function `popen`:

```
char testCmd[100];
char usrCmd[100];

strcpy(testCmd, "which ");
strcpy(usrCmd, "cat hello.txt");
strncat(testCmd, usrCmd, 93);

char path[100];
FILE *p = popen( testCmd , "r");
if(p ) {
    while(fgets(path, sizeof(path), p) != NULL) {
        printf("%s", path);
    }
}
```

The `which` command returns the path of its argument, passing `cat hello.txt` seem to work, too. If you are expecting nasty things like output redirection, it would make sense to send only the first word of the user input to `which`.

`which` prints either the path to the command (if it is in the path) or a newline (if the command is not found).

Comment: You have used C++ on a C question...

Comment: @John I will try to change for C but the core idea `which` and `popen` stays the same.

Comment: thanks for removing the C++ code.  BTW, you are correct, just pass the command itself to which -- "which cat", not "which cat hello.txt"

Comment: Thanks this really helped, works well now!

Answer (score 0):

stat system call provides information about a file provided you have given full path for the file name. If you want to know the files and types and whether that was exe and a Linux cmd, then you need to search from the root directory and then check each file and then determine the type etc. I suggest you to try to understand how a unix shell works then you will understand the answers for your question. exec family of system calls executes a program and you need to fork and then call exec in the child,  else your program will execute the new command.

Answer (score 0):

You write:

> wouldn't I need the cmd's path

Yes.  For any command without a path (cat not /usr/bin/cat), you would need to iterate through all the elements of the PATH variable, in pseudo code:

```
for (path in PATH) {
    cmdpath = concat(path, "/", cmd);
    stat(cmdpath, &statbuff);
    ...
}
```

but, having gone to all that trouble to duplicate the work in `execvp`, all you've done is create a place for weird timing ("race") bugs, possibly introducing a security hole.   See this wikipedia article for an intro to this topic: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_of_check_to_time_of_use

So the solution is generally the one you didn't want to use:

```
if (execvp(cmd, args) == -1) {
    printf("well, that didn't go well, did it?\n");
}
```

It's natural to want a "look before you leap" approach, but the "try it and see" approach is often simpler and more secure.

### EDIT

Your worry about clobbering a file is admirable, but that's exactly what happens in the "real" shell:

```
# date >victim
# cat victim 
Fri Feb 12 09:23:56 CST 2016
# shjsds >victim
shjsds: Command not found.
# cat victim
#                                  ! file was clobbered
```

Comment: I get that, but my problem mainly is that if i want to expand my code to include redirection with commands. If i do that and the user uses '>' (output) i would have to truncate the file, then call execvp which would mean if execvp fails, i truncated for no reason. which i want to prevent.